# xcode 5 constraints for iPhone 3.5-inch vs 4-inch

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I have 16 buttons which fills the 3.5-inch (simulator)iPhone screen, when i switch to 4-inch an empty area appears at the bottom. How should i set the constraints to have bigger buttons who fills the 4-inch screen ? I work with xcode 5.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Read original [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html). Working with Constraints in Interface Builder is well described there.

All in all If I were u I would use: Pin Menus -> Pin -> Spacing to nearest neighbor -> top, down left and right constraints ...

[image]